# How to write a program that shows if a number is prime and can display the prime numbers from 1 to 100 in a file

Tags: c++, primes

I am trying to write a program that will tell you if the numbered entered is prime or not and will write all the prime numbers from 1 to 100 to a file and displays the numbers. This is what I have so far, but I'm lost.

```
bool isPrime(int);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int num, answer, choice, i, numb=1;

    do
    {
        cout<< "Enter a number and I will tell you if it is prime or not."<<endl;
        cin>> num;

        if (isPrime(num))
            cout<<num<<" is a prime number."<<endl;
        else 
            cout<<num<< " is not a prime number."<<endl;

        cout<<"Would you like the first 100 prime numbers displayed? (1 for yes and 2 for no)"<<endl;
        cin>>choice;

        if (choice == 1)
        {
            while(numb<=100)
            { 
                i=2; 

                while(i<=numb)
                { 
                    if(num%i==0)
                        break;

                    i++;
                }

                if(i==num)
                    cout<<numb<<" is Prime"<<endl;

                numb++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"Would you like to run the program again? (1 for yes and 2 for no)"<<endl;
            cin>>answer;

            if (answer == 2)
            {
                exit(0);
            }
        }
        while (answer == 1);
    }

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}

bool isPrime (int number)
{
    int i;

    for (i=2; i<number; i++)
    {
        if (number % i == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;    
}
```

Comment: Looks like homework? Use homework tag.  What exactly is giving you problems?

Comment: I don't know how to get the 100 prime numbers to a file and display them.

Comment: Just as a comment: in isPrime it is sufficient to iterate to `(int(sqrt(number))+1)` instead of all the way up to `number`.

Answer (score 3):

Really feel you are over-thinking this. You've done the hard part which was writing the isprime function.

Displaying the numbers is trivial, just write a for loop to go through the numbers and check which are prime, if a specific number is prime then print it to screen.

Then just add the write to file inside the loop for those numbers you print to screen.

Comment: Ok so I added the loop to check which are prime: but the program says that there are errors.

Comment: @Student what are **errors**? We cannot read your mind, be *specific*.

Comment: It says that "answer" is being used without initializing, the one after the do-while loop.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just reuse your isPrime()?

```
cout<<"Would you like the first 100 prime numbers displayed? (1 for yes and 2 for no) <<endl;

cin>>choice;

for (i=2; i < 100; i++)
{
  if (isPrime(i)) cout << i << endl;
}
```

Comment: I entered it but it wouldn't let me run it because of errors. Can you see where I've made errors?

Comment: Can you post the errors from the compiler?  Most compiler errors tell the line numbers and other details.

Comment: It wont tell me the errors it just says that it cant run it. It was working but then I tried changing the text asking whether they wanted the prime numbers displayed and it showed there was an error.

Comment: Oh, wait, it says that 'answer' is being used without initializing. Its the one after the do-while loop.

Answer (score 1):

You're way over complicating things for yourself when printing all the primes from 1 to 100. Take a step back and think about what you want to do; cycle from 1 to 100, print the number if its prime.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; ++i) {
  if (isPrime(i))
  cout << i << endl;
}
```

Comment: I also entered this but it won't let me run it because of errors.

Comment: What kind of errors?  A spelling error is different than missing a function declaration.  Copy the exact text from the compiler.

Comment: bool isPrime(int);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
 int num, answer, choice;
do
{
cout<< "Enter a number and I will tell you if it is prime or not."<<endl;
cin>> num;

if (isPrime(num))
 cout<<num<<" is a prime number."<<endl;
else 
 cout<<num<< " is not a prime number."<<endl;

cout<<"Would you like the prime numbers from 1 to 100 displayed?"<<;
cout<<"(1 for yes and 2 for no)"<<endl;
cin>>choice;
if (choice == 1)
{ 
 for (int i=1; i <= 100; ++i)
  if (isPrime(i))
   cout<<i<<endl;
}
else
cout<<"Would you like to run the program again? (1 for yes and 2 for no)"<<endl;
 cin>>answer;

Comment: if (answer == 2)
 {
  exit(0);
 }

}
 while (answer == 1);

 system("pause");
 return 0;
}

bool isPrime (int number)
{
 
 int i;
 
 for (i=2; i<number; i++)
 {
  if (number % i == 0)
  {
   return false;
  }
 }
 
 return true; 
}

Comment: I think he means the error message the compiler is giving you. Are you a relatively new programmer? Sounds like you have a syntax Error.

Answer (score 0):

The `while` keyword of your `do-while` loop is on the wrong line.  It should follow the closing brace.  Compiler said around line 56 of the example code you posted.

After making changes to conform to standard C++, I compiled and ran the program.  I chose the option to list all the primes up to 100.  It is generous and displaying all the numbers, prime or not (hint:  even numbers after 2 are not prime).

I inserted the following lines at the beginning:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

I changed the main function from `_tmain` to `main` since I'm not using Visual Studio compiler.  Likewise the arguments too:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
```

By the way, if you are not passing parameters to your program, you can simplify the declaration of `main` to:

```
int main(void)
```

Here is a modification to speed up your prime detector:

```
bool isPrime (int number)
{
    int i;

    if (number == 2)
    {
        return true;
    }
    if ((number % 2) == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    for (i = 3; i < number; i += 2)
    {
        if (number % i == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;    
}
```

This cuts down the number of checks by half because every even number after 2 is not prime, only odd numbers.

Comment: Thank you I got it to work, however I am still missing writing the prime numbers that were displayed in a file. How would I go about doing that? Would I write it inside the loop?

Comment: See the answers from other people.  When the answer says `cout`, copy it, and change `cout` to your file stream, e.g. `text_file << i << endl;`.  Create the stream using `ofstream text_file("data.txt");` or something similar.